# how to obtain rows of the same type but that meet two conditions

Tags: sql-server

Hello everyone I hope you can help me, I have a table documents:
[image]

I would like to get ft 1 and ft 5 since it has type 2 dvvn and rc

> row1:ft 1 and
>   row2:ft 5

Comment: Can you please share your input , tables and expected output ?

Comment: row1:ft 1 and row2:ft 5

Comment: Ummm  what?  Do you want all rows where type2 is either dvvn or rc?

Answer (score 2):

Group by number and set the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
select number
from tablename
where type1 = 'ft' and type2 in ('dvvn', 'rc')
group by number
having count(distinct type2) = 2
```

If you want the same for all values of `type1`:

```
select type1, number
from tablename
where type2 in ('dvvn', 'rc')
group by type1, number
having count(distinct type2) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this meets the requirements. My version will work for two or more matches, switch to = 2 at the end if you need it to be strictly two matches.

```
SELECT T1.type1, T1.number, T2.type1, T2.number
FROM mytable T1
INNER JOIN mytable T2
   ON T1.type2 = T2.type2
   AND NOT (T1.type1 = T2.type1 AND T1.number = T2.number)
GROUP BY T1.type1, T1.number, T2.type1, T2.number
HAVING COUNT(*) >=2
```